# Retrieve data from LinqDataSource before Skip and Take happen?

Tags: c#, .net, linqdatasource

I have a GridView that uses LinqDataSource. The GridView has default paging enable. I would like to retrieve the data from LinqDataSource before the paging takes place so that I could calculate the Sum of one single column of the whole database using Linq2SQL.

Right now, I'm using `LinqDataSource_Selected` event with `LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs.Result`, but it only returns me the data AFTER paging (that is, the data on that page).

```
protected void linqDataSource_Selected(Object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)  
{  
    var totalTime = (e.Result as List<Ticket>).Sum(t => t.TimeSpent);  
    gridView.Columns[8].FooterText = "Sum: " + totalTime;  
}
```

So my question is: How can I retrieve data from LinqDataSource before paging takes place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LINQDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource_members.aspx) class has a [GetView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.queryabledatasource.getview.aspx) method which returns a [DataSourceView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datasourceview.aspx) object.  DataSourceView has an [ExecuteSelect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datasourceview.executeselect.aspx) method which will query the datasource directly.  You should be able to use LINQ syntax on the ExecuteSelect() method to get your sum.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying!  
Would you mind explaining more? I tried to call GetView() from my LINQDataSource (`linqDataSource.GetView()`), but Visual Studio gives me this error:  
`cannot access method 'GetView' here due to its protection level`

Comment: You're right, that GetView() method is protected.  I can't seem to find anything about querying directly using a LINQDataSource.  You might be better off creating a separate LINQDataSource just for the sum.